# How to handle the nil value in an array in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to save the element of an array that has the contents of xml parsed. Array elements when displayed in `NSLog` is as follows

```
ARRAY ELEMENTS (
)
2014-01-05 13:47:22.953 test[895:a0b]  ARRAY ELEMENTS (
)
2014-01-05 13:47:22.953 test[895:a0b]  ARRAY ELEMENTS (
)
2014-01-05 13:47:22.954 test[895:a0b]  ARRAY ELEMENTS (
)
2014-01-05 13:47:22.954 test[895:a0b]  ARRAY ELEMENTS (
)
2014-01-05 13:47:22.955 test[895:a0b]  ARRAY ELEMENTS (
    "M |HELLO| |HI|",
    "M |HELLO |HI|"

 )
```

when i try to access array element by using the following code and to get the substring that is by seperating the string with [pipe]"|"

```
for (int i =0; i < [finalArray count]; i++) {

    NSString *substring = [[NSString alloc]init];
    substring = [finalArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([NSNull null] == [finalArray objectAtIndex:i]) {
         NSLog(@"array object has nil value");             
    }
    else{
         NSArray *splitArray = [NSArray alloc];
         splitArray = [substring componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
         [finalSplitSMSArray addObject:splitSMSArray];
         splitSMSArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    }    
}
```

but exception comes as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8999fa0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like your finalArray does not contain strings, but at least on array, causing your error message. You might want to look into that

Answer (score 2):

i don't know what are you trying to accomplish here, but it seems that you need a lot of help :)

let's start by commenting some points:

1. you can't add a nil value to an array, which means you don't have to check it.
2. you have to change `NSString *substring = [[NSString alloc]init];` to `NSString *substring = [finalArray objectAtIndex:i];` as you have a memory leak here.
3. you don't have to allocate and initialise splitArray as it won't be used after the for loop.

**The answer to your question:** the exception you are getting is not because of null value, it means that you are trying to send a message "componentsSeparatedByString:" to an nsarray instead of nsstring.

> **make sure that the finalArray contains nsstring objects not nsarray.**

3- to simplify it try to change your code with this:

```
for (int i =0; i < [finalArray count]; i++) 
{
    NSString *substring = [finalArray objectAtIndex: i];

    if (![substring isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
         NSLog(@"this is not a string");
    else
    {
        NSArray *splitArray = [substring componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
        [finalSplitSMSArray addObject:splitSMSArray];
    }
 }
```

Comment: _+1_, But he has no memory leaks there with ARC.

Answer (score 0):

You could try testing whether `[substring length] == 0.`

Answer (score 0):

The error message `'-[__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]...` indicates that the method `componentsSeparatedByString:` is sent to an instance of a `NSMutableArray`.

So, even though you have declared `substring` as an `NSString`, during run-time it acts as an `NSMutableArray`.

My suggestion is that the error lies somewhere outside your code example.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion nil value in an array is not a problem, calling a method on nil will do nothing. **Look in debugger what you have in `substring` variable at this line**:

```
splitArray = [substring componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
```

as **it look that `substring` is an `NSArray` object** at this point and you are trying to execute a method `componentsSeparatedByString:` which **it doesn't implement**.

and I would change this:

```
NSArray *splitArray = [NSArray alloc];
```

into this:

```
NSArray *splitArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

you probably missed it :)

So the final code can look like this:

```
for (id item in finalArray) 
{
    if(![item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        continue;
    }

    NSArray *splitArray = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
    [finalSplitSMSArray addObject:splitArray];
}
```

Comment: In code above I have also changed this line `[finalSplitSMSArray addObject:splitSMSArray];`
into this `[finalSplitSMSArray addObject:splitArray];` assuming that it is what you wanted